# Find a patch of given size from numpy array having similar values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array, say 10x10 size. I want to find a patch in this array. The patch is defined by a mean value and a sigma such that the patch contains values in the following range: [μ ± σ]

Please see below pseudo-code:

```
a = np.array([[2, 1, 6, 7, 6, 5, 9, 1, 5, 6],
              [1, 7, 6, 0, 1, 9, 8, 1, 2, 0],
              [4, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 8, 7, 3, 3],
              [5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 7],
              [3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 8, 6, 1, 9],
              [4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 1, 9, 4, 5],
              [8, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8, 0],
              [4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 2, 2, 4],
              [3, 6, 1, 7, 7, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1],
              [5, 1, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 5, 0]])

patch_mu = 5
patch_sigma = 1
patch_size = 5x5 (5 rows, 5 cols)

def find_patch_index(arr, mu, sigma, size):
    # magic happens here
    return idx

idx = find_patch_index(a, patch_mu, patch_sigma, patch_size)
print(idx)  # should give 3, 1 (i.e., 3rd row, 1st col)
```

Patch has no specific definition. Basically in a 2D array (`a` in this case), I want to find a square that has elements are in a given range, i.e., [μ ± σ]

I am thinking to use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) but not getting a condition to satisfy the patch! Any lead, please?

Comment: Does this involve purely a 2D array, and a 2D patch? `np.where` would likely find values that are not guaranteed to be connected in 2D space.

Comment: I have a feeling that `scikit-image` may be a more appropriate package to use here.

Comment: what does `patch_size` do ? i assume you mean `patch_size = (5,5)` ?

Comment: Could you please provide a precise definition of "patch"?

Comment: @9769953: Yes, it is a 2D array and 2D patch. You are right about `np.where`. It is difficult to define such a condition for `np.where`

Comment: @9769953: Yes, we can consider it one channel image (though pixels are not representing color)

Comment: @AcaNg: Yes. I meant 5 rows, 5 columns, a square patch. `patch_size` defines a boundary. Inside a patch, all elements are in a given range, i.e., [μ ± σ]

Comment: @a_guest: Yes. Please see the updated question. A patch is basically a square having all the elements in a given range, i.e., [μ ± σ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) in the following way:

```py
valid = np.logical_and(
    patch_mu - patch_sigma <= a,
    patch_mu + patch_sigma >= a,
)
idx = np.argwhere(
    sliding_window_view(valid, patch_size).all(axis=(-2, -1))
)
```

---

For Numpy < 1.20 you can use [`stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) instead of `sliding_window_view`:

```py
as_strided(
    valid,
    shape=(valid.shape[0]-patch_size[0]+1, valid.shape[1]-patch_size[1]+1, *patch_size),
    strides=2*valid.strides,
)
```

Comment: so they added this as a replacement for `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` which is considered dangerous

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. However, I am having difficulty to understand it. First you computed `valid`, which is a boolean numpy array with shape 10, 10. Next sliding window is applied to this 2D boolean array with a size defined. What is the outcome here? Then you used `np.all` with last 2 axis. Can you please explain it i?

Comment: @RaviJoshi `valid` is an array that indicates which values lie in the desired range (`mu +/- sigma`). Then `sliding_window_view(valid, patch_size)` gives an array of shape `(5, 5, 5, 5)`. The first two dimensions corresponds to the original dimensions of `valid` (reduced by the patch size) and denote the left upper corner of each patch. The last two dimensions are the sliding window an hence correspond to the patches. So for example index `(i, j, k, l)` means take patch `(i, j)` (left upper corner) and then element `(k, l)` out of that patch. `all` simply ensures that the whole patch is valid.

Comment: @a_guest: Thank you very much. The `sliding_window_view(valid, patch_size)` is returning an array of shape `(6, 6, 5, 5)`. I understood the last two dimensions should be `(5, 5)` because we requested to get the patch of the same size. I am not sure about the first two dimension though

Comment: @a_guest: I got it. Given 10 elements in a row, picking a window of 5 elements can be done in 6 ways. So we should have 6 elements for rows, 6 for columns, and next 5x5 are  patch. Thank you very much for introducing `sliding_window_view` as I didn't use it so far. By the way, `sliding_window_view` requires NumPy of 1.20 or higher. Any alternative for NumPy 1.19 ?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Yes, you are right, it's `(6, 6, 5, 5)`. The first dimensions are truncated because the "last" patch cannot be further down than the `(5, 5)` row/col since it still needs to extend by 5x5 tiles patch size. If you draw a 10x10 square on paper and mark the tiles where possibly a left upper corner of a patch can be, you will see it is the left upper 6x6 sub-square. For Numpy < 1.20 you can use [`as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) (see my updated answer).